# Getting all types in a System namespace

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces, system

I want to print all classes of `using System` and `using System.Text`.

I write this code:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string nspace = "System.Text";
    var q = from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
            where t.IsClass && t.Namespace == nspace
            select t;
    q.ToList().ForEach(t => Console.WriteLine(t.Name));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

This code in namespaces that I wrote works fine, but in the `System` namespace it doesn't work and prints nothing.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to generalise this for ALL loaded assemblies, you can iterate all the loaded assemblies like so:

```
public static void Main()
{
    string nspace = "System.Text";

    foreach (var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
    {
        foreach (var type in assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsClass && t.Namespace == nspace))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(type.FullName);
        }
    }
}
```

If you only want to pick types from a particular assembly, then /u/HimBromBeere has posted a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `System.Text` is surely not **contained** in the executing assembly. It is just **referenced** from it.

You can just use the following:

```
var systemAssembly = typeof(anyTypeFromSystemText).Assembly;
var q = from t in systemAssembly.GetTypes()
        where t.IsClass && t.Namespace == nspace
        select t;
```